# атрибут download <a> не работает в firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5, asp.net-mvc, download

Привет всем!
есть ссылка, получаю ее с youtube, для скачивания видео (приложение asp.net mvc)
к тегу  подписываю атрибут download -  и после клика начинается скачивание видео во всех браузерах, за исключением firefox.

Скачать видео

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы скачивалось видео и в firefox тоже?

Comment: Можно html-код на всякий случай?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваш сайт domain1.com, а качаете с domain2.com? (в данном случае ютуб?)

```
<a href="http://domain.com/file.txt" download>click</a>
```

Увы, для фф необходим относительный адрес ресурса, либо см. CORS Headers FF

Как вариант - сделать отдельный метод контроллера, ссылку сделать относительной, но в беке запрос пойдёт на нужный вам адрес, например:

```
<a href="download?somefilename=file.txt" download>click</a>

public FileResult Download(string fileName)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"http://domain.com/file.txt");

    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Comment: а как можно сразу делать ссылку относительной?
и можно это как-то джаваскриптом обойти?

Comment: @Dmitriy, да, если сторонний сайт отдаёт файл именно на скачивание, то динамически можно создавать iframe с указанным URL - будет происходить скачивание с сохранением

Comment: А если сайт не отдает на скачивание?)) ну вот как в моем случае?

Comment: Тогда лучше только как я описал выше.